# How to specify parent directory without actual name in python

Tags: python

Hi all I have a script for getting Styles in a folder as follow

```
css_source_dir = os.path.join(sub_path, '01_South African Cases/Styles')
```

now what I want to do is to point to the /Styles directory, without having to specify the folder's Parent directory,...

for example, I want my code to look something like this:

```
css_source_dir = os.path.join(sub_path, '././Styles')
```

here the parent dir is not specified!
how can I archive this in python?

Comment: Something like `os.path.dirname(my_file.csv)`?  And the example shown should be `../../Styles`, as `./` is current directory.

Comment: you can perfectly use relative path. The current directory path is used. make sure you execute the python code from the proper directory.

Comment: `'././Styles'` specifies exactly the same filename as `'Styles'` - it looks only in the current directory, your version just redundantly looks up the current directory twice before looking for the file.  It's unclear what you had wanted this to mean - did you want to find Styles in whatever subdirectory it happened to be in?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the css files, within the Styles Directory, and not specify the parent folder of the '/Styles' as the parent folder name changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using glob and managed to iterate to my css files without specifying the actual path:

```
css_files = []
for file in glob.glob(sub_path + '/**', recursive=True):
    if file.endswith('.css'):
        css_source_dir = os.path.split(file)[0]
        css_files.append(file)
```